# send encrypted data to stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, encryption, cryptography

I have a symmetric key in the database which is used to decrypt the parameter passed to stored procedure, usually xml string. I open the symmetric key using a password.

Now this is a triple des algorithm created with  ALGORITHM = TRIPLE_DES.

**my question is how can I encrypt data from front end C# class and send to stored procedure.**

As far as I understand, this algorithm use  128-bit key, I have set init vector to 0. Now how can I fetch the binary key, to encrypt the data.

Pasted below is a snippet how I open a key in sql server Sproc.

```
select * from sys.symmetric_keys where [name]=Sym_Key'
if @@rowcount < 1
begin 
-- Symmetric encryption key not found
set @result=-1
goto ExitPoint
end

open symmetric key Sym_Key decryption by password =
'CF71939D674E4339B7D7BAD1EB792411E03DE5A'
```

Thanks for you patience

Comment: you want to `encrypt` the data in c#  , and to `DeCrypt` it in the Sql server ?

Answer (score 0):

I think this will probably help you:

[TripleDES Class (System.Security.Cryptography)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.tripledes.aspx)